# Was it able to retrieve data from a external web site which does not provide a API using YQL?

Tags: yql

I'd like to retrieve data from a web site ,which does not provide a API
Can I retrieve data using YQL?
ie: Can I custom the data parse  in the target URI with YQL?

Comment: Thanks Anton Babenko, XPath works great, but apart from XPath, is there any other method to parse the web html/data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is one of the most popular use case of YQL. Here is a [sample](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo%22%20and%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22yfi_headlines%22%5D/div%5B2%5D/ul/li/a%27&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys). But it is not working when trying to retrieve data from web-page which is dissallowed for spider access (via robots.txt, for example).

Comment: Thanks ,it works great, but apart from Xpath, is there any other method to parse the web html/data?

Comment: Xpath is the main one and most universal. It is possible to parse HTML, CSS, RSS/XML using it or special datatables provided by YQL.

Comment: Can I build a open table to parse the specific html at target site? which method is better compare to Xpath?

Comment: Yes, you can. You have a choice of using Xpath expressions inside YQL statement directly or write javascript code which will deal with the structure of target page and do what you want. I can't find good source right now, but I think I saw some good examples on [Christian Heilman blog](http://christianheilmann.com/tag/yql/). I also recommend you to look for samples and possible use cases in [the official datatables](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you're trying to do, the only reasonable answer here is…

*Yes.*